# How to use a backup printer?

Tags: printer

I have a check-in application that uses a label printer. When the printer runs out of labels I would like to simply unplug it and connect an identical label printer with a full spool of labels.

My problem is that, even though the printer it is exactly the same make and model, Windows creates a new printer and adds a suffix "(copy 2)" to the name. The labels are set to print to the label printer automatically, without having to select the printer.

Is there a way to force Windows not to rename the backup printer when it is connected?

Thanks!

Comment: I think not, unless you can spoof the hardware IDs that Windows obtains from the device.

Comment: Is it possible to leave both plugged in, and move the partially-completed *print job* to the backup? [*Caveat*: I have not attempted this.]

Answer (score 0):

If the printer uses a USB port, then Windows will see a different printer when you plug the new one in.

However, your idea will work fine if the printer is connected via a serial or parallel port, as these ports do not carry any printer identification.

It will also work if the printer is connected via a network port - as long as you give the printer a permanent IP address. If you use DHCP, even with a reserved address, then the DHCP server will not recognise the new printer's Mac address and give it a different IP address from the old one. In that case the data will no longer get to the printer.